# list files from directory, does it read only file name details or the entire file data from directory

Tags: java, file-io, io

If we want to list the files from the directory.. generally we use listFiles() on that folder..

But when you execute the above method call does it retrieve only files name information or it retrieves the file content also??

Example: 
Folder: MyFolder, it contains A1.html(size of files is 100MB) file.
So when I tries to list the files in the MyFolder, will it retrieve total 100MB of A1.html or only filename(A1.html) it retrieves ??

Can someone answer this please if you have idea...?

Comment: Thankfully it does not read the content...

Answer (score 0):

It will only read the metadata about files which doesn't include the file content but will contain things like:

1. File Size
2. Extension
3. Absolute Path

Answer (score 0):

> Example: Folder: MyFolder, it contains A1.html(size of files is 100MB)
>   file. So when I tries to list the files in the MyFolder, will it
>   retrieve total 100MB of A1.html or only filename(A1.html) it retrieves
>   ??

No it will not retrieve 100MB of Data , it doesn't retrieve file contents

As [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) Says

```
public File[] listFiles()
```

> `Returns` : An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in
>   the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be
>   empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract
>   pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.